# Basic programming on Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I'm reading through the documentation here https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html

and it says "In order to listen for this event, you would use..."

```
Coin.Sent().watch({}, '', function(error, result) {
     if (!error) {
        console.log("Coin transfer: " + result.args.amount +
        " coins were sent from " + result.args.from +
        " to " + result.args.to + ".");
        console.log("Balances now:\n" +
        "Sender: " + Coin.balances.call(result.args.from) +
        "Receiver: " + Coin.balances.call(result.args.to));
     }
})
```

Now, this is not part of the contract itself, so where would I run this code?

Comment: See if https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/13/building-decentralized-apps-with-ethereum-and-javascript/ helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's a JavaScript code. You can use this javascript as client (web3j) to observe events

Comment: Hmm How would I allow connect a client to the EVM?

Comment: There are geth, parity. For dev ethereumjs-testrpc is great